Socket.io events in React.js and Node.js not being triggered
I'm building a chat application in React js and Node js. The events that I have written in React.js and Node.js do not seem to be triggered. I can login and see data in both the browser and the console, but as soon as I installed Socket.IO for the client and server, not only did I get issues from Socket.IO on the client side, none of the events are being triggered.
socketConnect.js in the client side
import { useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client"

function useSocket (user, dispatch) {

    useEffect(() => {

        const socket = socketIOClient.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000")

        socket.emit("join", user)

        socket.on("typing", (user) => {
            console.log("Event", user)
        })

        socket.on("friends", (friends) => {
            console.log("Friends", friends)
        })

        socket.on("online", (user) => {
            console.log("Online", user)
        })

        socket.on("offline", (user) => {
            console.log("Offline", user)
        })
    }, [dispatch])

}

export default useSocket

/socket/index.js in the server side
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const { sequelize } = require("../models");

const users = new Map();
const userSockets = new Map();
const SocketServer = (server) => {

    const io = socketIo(server)
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        socket.on("join", async (user) => {
            let sockets = [];
            if (user.has(user.id)){
                const existingUser = users.get(user.id)
                existingUser.sockets = [...existingUser.sockets, ... [socket.id]]
                users.set(user.id, existingUser);
                sockets = [...existingUser.sockets, ... [socket.id]]
                userSockets.set(socket.id, user.id)
            } else {
                users.set(user.id, {id: user.id, sockets: [socket.id]})
                sockets.push(socket.id);
                userSockets.set(socket.id, user.id)
            }
            const onlineFriends = []; 

            const chatters = getChatters(user.id) 

            console.log(chatters);

            for (let i = 0; i < chatters.length; i++){
                if (users.has(chatters[i])){
                    const chatter = users.get(chatters[i])
                    chatter.sockets.forEach(socket => {
                        
                        try {
                            io.to(socket).emit("online",user);
                        } catch (error) {
                            
                        }

                    })
                    onlineFriends.push(chatter.id)
                }
            }
            sockets.forEach(socket => {
                try {
                    io.to(socket).emit("friends", onlineFriends)

                } catch (error) {
                    
                }
            })

            console.log("New User Joined: ", user.firstName);

            io.to(socket.id).emit("typing", "User typing...")

        })

        socket.on("disconnect", async () => {

            if (userSockets.has(socket.id)){

                const user = users.get(userSockets.get(socket.id))

                if (user.sockets.length > 1) {

                    user.sockets = user.sockets.filter(sock => {

                        if (sock !== socket.id) return true

                        userSockets.delete(sock)
                        return false
                    })

                    users.set(user.id, user)
                } else {
                    
                    const chatters = await getChatters(user.id)

                    for (let i = 0; i < chatters.length; i++){
                        if (users.has(chatters[i])){
                            users.get(chatters[i]).sockets.forEach(socket => {
                                
                                try {
                                    io.to(socket).emit("offline",user);
                                } catch (error) {
                                    
                                }
        
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    userSockets.delete(socket.id);  
                    users.delete(user.id)
                }
            }
        });
    })
}

const getChatters = async (userId) => {

    try {

        const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(`
        select "cu"."userId" from "ChatUsers" as cu
        inner join (
            select "c"."id" from "Chats" as c
            where exists (
                select "u"."id" from "Users" as u
                inner join "ChatUsers" on u.id = "ChatUsers"."userId"
                where u.id = ${parseInt(userId)} and c.id = "ChatUsers"."chatId"
            )
        ) as cjoin on cjoin.id = "cu"."chatId"
        where "cu"."userId" != ${parseInt(userId)}
    `)

        return results.length > 0 ? results.map(el => el.userId) : []

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return []
    }
}

module.exports = SocketServer


root index.js in the server side
const express = require("express");
const config = require('./config/app')
const router = require('./router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));

const port = config.appPort;

const server = http.createServer(app);
const SocketServer = require("./socket")
const io = socketIo(server);

SocketServer(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("New client connected: ", socket.id);

    socket.on("join", (user) => {
        console.log("New user joined: ", user);
        io.to(socket.id).emit("typing", "User typing...");
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected: ", socket.id);
    });
});



server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)    
});



Chat.js which renders the components
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import useSocket from './hooks/socketConnect'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import { fetchChats } from '../../store/actions/chat'
import FriendList from './components/FriendList/FriendList'
import Messenger from './components/Messenger/Messenger'
import './Chat.scss'

const Chat = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const user = useSelector(state => state.authReducer.user)

    useSocket(user, dispatch)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchChats()).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <div id='chat-container'>
            <Navbar />
            <div id='chat-wrap'>
                <FriendList />
                <Messenger />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat





I have multiple users in the database. When a user logs in and is online, another user from the database, if logged in, will be notified from the console, but none of the events are being triggered.


issues from Socket.IO on the client side can you describe the issues, are there any errors in the console for example.

No error is displayed in the console nor the terminal. The only issue is that, for example, in the browser when I refresh the page as I'm logged in,  the console should display the message "New user joined' which is in the index.js in the socket folder. But the message is not being displayed possibly indicating that the event is not being triggered. Neither is the typing event.
